# antd tabs -> how to remove

Tags: reactjs, tabs, dropdown, antd

please help.

I want to remove a tab, but tabitems are redefined.
If I remove button tab2 out of tab1,tab2,tab3, only tab1,tab3 remain.
but if I remove 3 there, tab1, tab2 remain.\

when i debug, activekey is changed, but when click t remove button, activekey is not changed

```
    import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react'; import Image from "next/image"; import { Title, ButtonWrap } from '../../styles/com'; import { Dropdown, Card, Button, Divider, Tabs } from 'antd'; import { MoreOutlined, CheckOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons'; import ArtsInsertFormTab from './ArtsInsertFormTab';
    
    
    export default function ArtsInsertTab (props) {
    
    const items = [
        {
            key: '1',
            label: 'delete'
        },
    ];
    
    const remove = () => {
        console.log(activeKey)
        let newActiveKey = activeKey;
        let lastIndex = -1;
        tabitems.forEach((item, i) => {
        if (item.key === key) {
            lastIndex = i - 1;
        }
        });
    
        const newPanes = tabitems.filter((item) => item.key !== activeKey);
        if (newPanes.length && newActiveKey === activeKey) {
        if (lastIndex >= 0) {
            newActiveKey = newPanes[lastIndex].key;
        } else {
            newActiveKey = newPanes[0].key;
        }
        }
        setTabItems(newPanes);
        setActiveKey(newActiveKey);
    };
    
    
    const tabitem = new Array(props.imgList.length).fill(null).map((_, i) => {
        return {
            label: <Image alt="example" src={props.imgList[i].url} width='60' height='60'/>,
            key: String(i + 1),
            children:
            <div>
              <Card
                data-props='collapse'
                bordered={false}
                extra={
                  <>
                    <Dropdown menu={{items, onClick: remove,}}>
                      <a onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
                        <MoreOutlined/>
                      </a>
                    </Dropdown>
                  </>
                }>
                <ArtsInsertFormTab props={props.imgList[i]}/>
              </Card>
              <ButtonWrap>
                <Button onClick={cancleButton} size='large'><div>cancle</div></Button>
                <div>
                  <Button size='large'><div>dd</div></Button>
                  <Button type='primary' size='large' onClick={saveButton} icon={<CheckOutlined/>}><div>save</div></Button>
                </div>
              </ButtonWrap>
            </div>
        };
      });
    
    const venueId = props.venueId;
    const formData = new FormData(); 
    const [activeKey, setActiveKey] = useState(initialItems[0].key);
    const [tabitems, setTabItems] = useState(tabitem);
    const [isCheckUse, setIsCheckUse] = useState(false); 
    const [formState, setFormState] = useState({
        artwork_title : "",
        artwork_artist_nm : "",
        artwork_date : "",
        artwork_img_alt : "",
        artwork_meterial : "",
        artwork_size : "",
        mapping_list : "",
        artwork_location : "",
        artwork_intro_url : "",
        artwork_view_url : "",
        artwork_view_playtime : "",
        artwork_next : "",
        artwork_tag1 : "",
        artwork_tag2 : "",
        artwork_tag3 : "",
        artwork_tag4 : "",
        use_yn : "",
    
    });     
    
    
    // useEffect(() => {
    //     console.log("activekey: "+activeKey);
    //     key = activeKey;
    // }, [activeKey]);
    
    
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("tabtimeslend: "+tabitems.length);
    }, [tabitems]);
    
    const cancleButton = ()=>{
    
    }
    const saveButton = ()=>{
        //formValidation();
        
        formData.append("exhibition_nm", formState.exhibition_nm);
        formData.append("exhibition_start_date", formState.exhibition_start_date);
        formData.append("exhibition_end_date", formState.exhibition_end_date);
        formData.append("exhibition_inline_text", formState.exhibition_inline_text);
        formData.append("exhibition_img_alt", formState.exhibition_img_alt);
        formData.append("exhibition_text", formState.exhibition_text);
        formData.append("multipartFiles_map", formState.multipartFiles_map);
        formData.append("exhibition_intro_url", formState.exhibition_intro_url);
        formData.append("exhibition_img_ext", props.imgList[0].ext);
        formData.append("exhibition_img_type", 'testImage');
        formData.append("multipartFiles_img", new Blob([JSON.stringify(props.imgList[0])], { type: "multipart/form-data}" }));
        formData.append("exhibitionMapImgCnt", 1);
        formData.append("useyn", isCheckUse  ? 'Y' :'N');
    
        fetch(`http://localhost:8090/api/exhibition/insertExhibition`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
        processData: false, 
        contentType: false,
        headers: {
        }
    
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            alert('accepte');
        });
    }
    
    
    const ontabChange = (newActiveKey) => {
        console.log(newActiveKey)
        key = newActiveKey;
        //setActiveKey(newActiveKey);
    };
    
    
    
    return (
        <>
        <Title>
            <h1>test</h1>
        </Title>
        <Tabs
            style={{minWidth: '1400px'}}
            defaultActiveKey="1"
            onChange={ontabChange}
            type="card"
            tabPosition="right"
            items={tabitems}
        >
        </Tabs>
        </>
    )
    }
```

Comment: Welcome! ['Can somebody help me?' is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541). Can you please ask an actual question? You can see [ask] for guidance.